# Cross migration of VMs

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, live-migration, shared-storage

I have two w2k8r2 machines, that are in cluster, There are also two machines that are used as shared storage (with StarWind installed). On each node of the cluster there is one VM. So tell me please is it possible to cross-live=migrate VMs? Other words can I perform Live Migration of each VM, that are on different cluster nodes, simultaneously?

Thak you very much for now.

Answer (score 0):

can't see why not - this works with kvm, why not with hyper-v?

Comment: can with ESX(i) too

Comment: I dont know why - I'm startin LM of first machine, then second, and getting error on the second one (event ID 1205). Has anyone actually tried this? @Chopper3 - I had success with ESX too.

Comment: I guess you might want to check the migration related logs, to see what exactly fails

Comment: That error suggest you're losing iSCSI connectivity, are you using that for quorum/msdtc?

Comment: That is not cause of connectivity - usual single machine Live Migration works fine, but not cross one. And I can't find any source that would tell if it actually supported.

Comment: can you migrate one VM, make sure it finishes migrating, and then start the migration of the second one? I do suspect hyper-v has a limitation of a single migration at a time

Comment: That is I am afraid of - impossibility. So please, if anyone had success with some kind of my issue or knows something that can help - let me now.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying Hyper-V Live Migration with iSCSI there are some setup requirements that I'm not remembering off the top of my head that you need to do with iSCSI Initiator and storage to make sure the LUN can hop to the other server.  Normally targets are initiator specific, and with different SAN software you perform the steps differently to support clustering of the LUN/volume.

I would think your storage vender would have documentation on the clustered storage part, and Hyper-V Live Migration would have documentation on the things to check to ensure the LUN "hops" from one server to another.

I also remember in 2008 R2 clustered shared volumes (many nodes write to one volume) is a good thing, allowing you to store all VM's on one LUN rather than their own.

Yes I've seen migrations simultaneously in opposite directions, it may have been Quick Migration though.

Lastly the big no no is to have the host NIC and the iSCSI NIC be the same one.  Really in your scenario you want at least three, one dedicated to host, one dedicated to guest network access, and one dedicated to iSCSI on host.  Microsoft actually recommends 4, with the 4th dedicated to Live Migration. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428137(WS.10).aspx